# How do I get past init error with tweepy on sl4a?

Tags: tweepy, sl4a

When I run the sample script from tweepy on sl4a I get the following init error:

TypeError: **init**() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
I have put in my key, token and secrets.

Comment: I was using the code example directly from the tweepy website (the only changes I made were for my specific keys and tokens.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using the same version of Tweepy on your Android device as on your computer. Make sure that both are using the latest version of Tweepy, and try running the example again.